# Wiki.js doesn't work with a preexisting repo

Tags: git, docker, gitlab, wiki.js

Running docker container with Wiki.JS on my Linux host machine. Everything working good, but I want use Wiki.JS feature for side-to-side synchronization via Git. I use local Gitlab server and create new repo (try clean and try with readme.md file). In Wiki.JS I write all requisites for connection, and it working good. But after all I have different problems. The main problem error via git syncs:

```
From 172.20.5.217:documentation-group/wiki.js * branch master -> FETCH_HEAD fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

I'm understand that problem with git at local repo in docker container, because its non empty. Ewereywhere give advise about use *git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories*. But I dont how use this command in docker container with git. On host machine git is not installed.

I find closed github ticket whith same problem https://github.com/Requarks/wiki/issues/374 and https://github.com/Requarks/wiki/issues/507 where creator of Wiki.JS give answer about delete local /repo folder.

So, my question is that I want to understand where can I find the repository? I'll try *locate git* and *locate repo* on host machine, but I can't find that repo.

Answer (score 0):

For me I was able to just do the following:

```
sudo docker exec -it my_wikijs /bin/bash
```

Then using find:

```
find ./ -name repo
```

It returned:

```
./data/repo
```

The only other thing I would mention is that I would strongly suggest removing the entire `YAML` header or atleast the tags component of the `YAML` header before importing because I've had issues with that before.